# how to set precision value for double datatype in mysql workbench schema

Tags: mysql, types, mysql-workbench

I want to have double datatype with precision of two points. Is there any way it can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
field_name NUMERIC(11,2)
```